# save what is written in buttons in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm creating a list of movies with a button under each one that says "seen" or "unseen". I need to save in localstorage the state of this button (if it has the text "seen" or "not seen") and when reloading the page, stay as it was before. Since it's a very extensive list of movies (I added a few just for testing), I'm having a hard time saving each button without having to save one by one in the code. P.S. All buttons are the same, just changing the id of each one according to the movie. I created a function that takes the exact button that was clicked, and it can be seen in the "const id" that is in the code. My code must be a mess as I'm quite a beginner, but I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do :)

```js
function pesquisar() {
    var input,filtro,menu,menuItens,links;
    input = document.getElementById("pesquisa");
    filtro = input.value.toUpperCase();
    menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    menuItens = menu.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for(var i=0;i<menuItens.length;i++) {
        links = menuItens[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        if(links.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtro)>-1){ 
            menuItens[i].style.display="";
        }else{
            menuItens[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
};


//target para cada id de cada filme
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach( function(button) {
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    const el = event.target || event.srcElement;

    const id = el.id;

    console.log(id)


    //pega o elemento do id e muda o texto para "visto"
    var visto = document.getElementById(id).textContent = "Visto"
    visto
    
    //pega o elemento pelo id e adiciona uma classe chamada "visto"
    var classe = setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add("visto")},100)
    classe

    //variavel que verifica se o id contem a classe visto
    const verdade = document.getElementById(id).classList.contains("visto") 
    console.log(verdade)
    
    //verifica se o id contem a classe "visto" e modifica ou não o elemento
    if(verdade == true){
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = "Não Visto"

        setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("visto")},100)
        
    }else{
    }

    

});
});
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #141414;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
}

p {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
   margin-left: 5%;
   margin-top: 5%;
}

img {
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    /* border: 4px solid #000000; */
    
}

label {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 3%;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*border: 4px solid white;*/
    width: 250px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    

}

#busca_filmes {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#pesquisa {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd
}

button, input {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s;
    border: none;
    background: #413f3d;
}

button:hover {
    background: #585857;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    
    <title>Filmes</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>100 Filmes para se ver antes de morrer!</h1>

    <nav id="busca_filmes">
        <input type="text" id="pesquisa" placeholder="Buscar..."/>
    </nav>
    <div  id="menu">
    <label for="matrix" >
        <p>Matrix <br> (1999)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/matrix.jpg" title="Matrix (1999)">
        <br>
        <div class="text">
            <Button id="matrix">Não visto</Button>
        </div>
        </label> 

    <label for="seven" >
        <p>Seven: Os Sete Crimes Capitais (1995)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/se7en.jpg" title="Seven: Os Sete Crimes Capitais (1995)">
        <br>
        <div class="text">
            <Button id="seven" >Não visto</Button>
        </div>
        </label>

    <label for="sonho_de_liberdade" >
        <p>Um Sonho de Liberdade (1994)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/sonho_de_liberdade.png" title="Um Sonho de Liberdade (1994)">
         <br>
         <div class="text">
            <Button id="sonho_de_liberdade" >Não visto</Button>
           </div>
        </label>

    <label for="os_suspeitos" >
        <p>Os Suspeitos <br>(1995)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/os_suspeitos.jpg" title="Os Suspeitos (1995)">
        <br>
        <div class="text">
            <Button id="os_suspeitos" >Não visto</Button>
           </div>
        </label>
    
    <label for="pulp_fiction" >
        <p>Pulp Fiction: Tempo de Violência (1994)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/pulp_fiction.jpg" title="Pulp Fiction: Tempo de Violência (1994)">
        <br>
        <div class="text">
            <Button id="pulp_fiction" >Não visto</Button>
        </div>
        </label>

    <label for="taxi_driver" >
        <p>Taxi Driver: Motorista de Táxi (1976)</p>
        <img class="margem" src="img/taxi_driver.jpg" title="Taxi Driver: Motorista de Táxi (1976)">
        <br>
        <div class="text">
            <Button id="taxi_driver" >Não visto</Button>
        </div>
        </label>

    </div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scrypt.js"></script>
</html>
```